# Convert a ee.Geometry() into a Leaflet polygon

Tags: python, leaflet, polygon, google-earth-engine

I'm using the Leaflet and gee API in a Python notebook.
In this notebook I'd like to display a featureCollection as a layer on a Leaflet map.

```py
#retreive the asset
asset_descripsion = 'Glad_' + country_selection + '_boundaries'
folder = ee.data.getAssetRoots()[0]['id'] + '/'

asset = ee.FeaturCollection(folder+asset_descripsion)

#create the map 
m = Map(center=center, zoom=zoom)
dark_matter_layer = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.CartoDB.DarkMatter)
m.add_layer(dark_matter_layer)

#add the layer 
asset_geom = ee.FeatureCollection(asset).geometry().getInfo()['coordinates']#polygon = Polygon(
    locations=asset_geom,
    color="green",
    fill_color="green"
)
m.add_layer(polygon);
m
```

Problem the way leaflet and gee construct polygon is not compatible so my Map end up like that
[image]

instead of the Argentina boundaries that I have in GEE
[image]

Does anyone know how to perform this trick ?

Comment: https://macwright.org/lonlat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who end up here [geemap](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap#usage) provides a complete integration of earthengine object into leaflet maps.

Then to display a `ee.geometry()` :

```py
import geemap
import ee

m = geemap.Map()

asset = ee.FeaturCollection(assetId)

m.addLayer(asset, {}, 'asset')
```